Force user to crop image to predefined size (like avatar picker)
I have a Next.js app, and I want to let the user upload an avatar (i.e., profile image).
I want to force the user to crop the image they upload to a circle.
Like this:

Googles' profile image picker
I would appreciate multiple approaches I could consider. I don't know if it's relevant, but eventually, the image would get uploaded to firebase storage.

I found this: react-avatar-editor, which does the job.
I'm adding this example, which also helped me.
